# Lazy<T> as Lazy<object> possible?

Tags: c#, generics

Is it possible to cast a `Lazy<T`> *instance* as a `Lazy<object>` when all I have is an object reference?
This returns null:

```
var result = obj as Lazy<object>;
```

That makes sense to me. It should be null because its not a `Lazy<object>`. But is there another way to interrogate to find out what T actually is or cast to object? I actually don't care what T actually is in this case. I just need the `.Value` reference.

**Some background**

So this is really a curiosity question. It could be applied to any object specifying a generic (i.e. `List<T>`). But here's the specific case:
I'm sticking a `Lazy<T>` provider in a cache. I know what T is when I put it in and I know what T is in the normal use when i pull it out.
However, in one case when I'm managing the cache, I don't know what T is and really I don't want to interact with it except to send its value to a serializer. I'm just concerned I'm missing some obvious way to achieve this without creating a way to track it ahead of time or change a bunch of method signatures/calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what the `dynamic` keyword is for.  It uses the same reflection solution underneath as @SledgeHammer's answer, except that it has a cache for the getter delegates so it's a lot faster if you do it more than once for the same `T`.  It's also a lot shorter and easier to read (and write).

```
object result = (obj as dynamic).Value;
```

Comment: YES! This is what my brain kept telling me but I kept think run into the same issues so I didn't try. Clearly I didn't understand the mechanics underneath dynamic so thanks for that info.

Answer (score 1):

The way you asked the question, you would need to use reflection (or expression trees) to do it:

```
    Lazy<int> l = new Lazy<int>(() => 5);

    object o = l;

    object val = o.GetType().GetProperty("Value").GetGetMethod().Invoke(o, null);
```

Comment: I don't really think there is a need to check with `HasValue` (nor there is such property). Did you mean `IsValueCreated`? Either way, the purpose of the type is precisely to allow for lazy initialization.

Comment: @LeandroTaset -- oops... I was thinking nullable... I've took out the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Classes in C# cannot be covariant, so there is no way for you to treat that object instance as a `Lazy<object>`.  You'll have to create a *new* `Lazy` object that simply uses the other `Lazy` to determine what the value should be.  Doing so is simple enough:

```
Lazy<T> oldLazy = ComputeOldLazy();
Lazy<object> newLazy = new Lazy<object>(() => oldLazy.Value);
```

Comment: perfectly good answer for the way I originally asked it. Edited the question to make it more clear. I do not know what T is when i get the original reference. In fact I only know its a Lazy anything because I stuck it in there. I just have an object reference.

Comment: @user2245759 It's not acceptable to edit your question into a completely different question after getting an answer.  If you want to ask a different question then you should ask a different question.  Additionally, even with the change to your question, this still answers it.  This code doesn't care what `T` is.

Comment: @Servy: Why in the world would you say such thing? First, it is not a *completely different question*. Second, would you please provide a reference to the law that sanctions this kind of edit by the OP? Your answer is incorrect simply because there is no `T` to reference.

Comment: @Servy not sure what to do with that. I was really just trying t provide greater clarification, not change the question I was originally trying to communicate. That was the intention. I asked, edited, and commented in good faith. If its the points you would like, simply add to your answer that if the code cannot specify T, then you cannot get a reference. I'll mark it and then it will be there for posterity.

Comment: @LeandroTaset To say that you have a `Lazy<T>` reference, and then to edit the question to say you *don't* have a `Lazy<T>` reference is in fact a completely different question, as evidenced by the fact that I answered the question that was asked, and then, after providing the correct answer, the OP is attempting to assert that he doesn't actually want that question answered.  If you want a reference, [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260066/drastic-question-revision) is a reference.

Comment: @Servy: So, it is more relevant that you get a correct answer to an incorrectly formulated question, than helping the OP with his actual issue? That does not sound right in any way.

Comment: @LeandroTaset If the OP has realized that they now in fact have a different question, based on answers they've gotten from an earlier question, they can ask a new question.  Nobody is stopping them from doing that.  Creating a site filled with answers to completely different questions makes the site far less useful as a resource, than having a site where there is a question and answers to that actual question asked.

Comment: @Servy: Simple thing! Just withdraw your answer as it is no longer relevant in light of the OP mending his own question.

Comment: This solution is just really bad. Why randomly new up objects you don't need? Yes, the question was not well asked, but a good answer should not be so literal :).

Comment: @SledgeHammer But you *do* need the new object, to actually answer the question that is asked.  The question asks how to get a `Lazy<object>` from a `Lazy<T>`.  The *only* way to do that is to create a new object.  It's not *possible* to get a `Lazy<object>` any other way.  If you think that the question isn't asking something that you think is useful, then, that's a perfectly fine opinion, by all means, point that out to the question author in a comment if you want to.

Comment: I did not directly assert I knew T.  From the original wording you could imply that I did or did not have it, either way.  My edit was to eliminate ambiguity. I up voted your answer, since it clearly defines what could not be done in either interpretation of the original text and the revised text. It has value either way. However, I awarded the answer elsewhere since it describes what can be done (though I'll probably change my signatures as matter of preference before reflecting).

Comment: @servy no he asked how to get the value genericlly. His first idea was to convert it to lazy object but that was the wrong path to solving the actual problem.

Comment: @SledgeHammer The best way to solve the *actual* problem is not to store the `Lazy` in an `object` in the first place, so you don't end up using extremely inefficient and non-statically typed operations like reflection, which is virtually certainly unnecessary.  But hey, you wouldn't suggest that, because you're not one to go down the wrong path to solving the actual problem.  But the OP didn't provide the information about what their *actual* problem is, they asked how to get a `Lazy<object>`, and since that's all the question actually asked, that's all that could be answered in an answer.

Comment: @Servy, so you never have to pass around different types to a method lol? Gotta work on your reading comprehension :), OP said: "I actually don't care what T actually is in this case. I just need the .Value reference.".

Comment: @SledgeHammer Of course I pass around different types to a method.  What does that have to do with storing a `Lazy` in a variable of type `object`?  Do I typically remove all static type information from my object and then force myself to use reflection to actually use them?  No, very rarely.  Missing the title of the question and the actual question asked, "Is it possible to cast a `Lazy<T>` instance as a `Lazy<object>` when all I have is an object reference?" doesn't exactly speak to your reading comprehension skills.

Comment: So how would you pass around a Lazy<T> and get the value with using reflection? You would double lazy it like you did here? That's not generic at all. lol... for what is now the 5th time you've been told, he asked about converting it to a Lazy<object>, but stated his end game was to get the value generically for any type. You really need to get over converting it to a Lazy<object>, you seem obsessed with that... he simply threw that idea out there, he didn't say he had to do it that way.

Comment: @SledgeHammer Without knowing what he's *actually* doing, we couldn't meaningfully comment on the appropriate way of accomplishing that task.  Like I said, passing around a `Lazy` as an `object` is virtually certainly wrong.  If you *have* done that, then you need to use reflection to get the value out *which is why you shouldn't be doing that*.  The hypocrisy of condemning my answer for doing what the question actually asked, rather than providing a good solution for the OP's actual problem, while *providing a horrible solution for the OP's actual problem* is rather telling.